# Хранение массива объектов дочерних классов в файле

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп, fstream

Написал простинькую иерархию классов которая реализует класс People и два дочерних класса Teacher и Student. Как мне хранить объекты дочерних классов в файле?

```
 class People
{
protected:
    std::string m_name;
    int m_age;
    std::string m_sex;

public:
    People(std::string name = "", int age = 0, std::string sex = "")
        : m_name(name), m_age(age), m_sex(sex) {}

std::string getName()
{
    return m_name;
}

int getAge()
{
    return m_age;
}

std::string getSex()
{
    return m_sex;
}
};

class Teacher : public People
{
private:
    std::string m_position;
    float m_experience;

public:
    Teacher(std::string name = "", int age = 0, std::string sex"", 
    std::string position = "", float experience = 0.0)
    : People(name, age, sex),
        m_position(position), m_experience(experience) {}

std::string getPosition()
{
    return m_position;
}

float getExperience()
{
    return m_experience;
}
};

class Student : public People
{
private:
    std::string m_faculty;
    double m_average_rating;

public:
    Student(std::string name = "", int age = 0, std::string sex = "", 
std::string faculty = "", double average_rating = 0.0)
    :  People(name, age, sex),
        m_faculty(faculty), m_average_rating(average_rating) {}

std::string getFaculty()
{
    return m_faculty;
}

double getAverageRating()
{
    return m_average_rating;
}
};
```

Comment: В бинарном или текстовом виде. При такой постановке вопроса лично я точнее ответить не в состоянии... Впрочем, я не очень знаю, что такое "*объкиты*"...

Comment: Покажите, как именно у вас эти объекты хранятся?

Comment: в качестве инструмента позволяющую решить эту проблему могу посоветовать `Boost.Serialization`.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Думаю, в данном случае - это из пушки по воробьям...

Comment: @Harry скорее всего, но в случае если действительно нужно сохранять достаточно большие объемы данных, еще и исходя из иерархии классов, то это самое то

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch По-моему, тут очевидное учебное задание...

Comment: @Harry возможно (я не учился в универе так что понятия не имею о домашке), но, ИМХО, лучше научится что-то делать верно (хотя бы прочувствовать концепцию), нежели наскоро лепить что-то, что нельзя будет поддерживать в будущем (ввиду разростания иерархии классов и общего функционала)

Comment: Если будете сохранять в начале файла количество элементов массива, то это облегчит вашу задачу по чтению их обратно в массив, а также контроль целостности файла

Answer (score 1):

Если делать свой велосипед, то проще всего таким образом:

1. Исхожу из предположения, что данные объектов будут сохраняться в
   текстовый файл. Если необходимо сохранять в двоичном формате, то тип
   выходного параметра нужно изменить
2. В базовом классе создаем два виртуальных метода getData() возвращающий строку и setData(..) принимающий на вход строку с данными. Эти
   методы могут быть абстрактными или содержать код, обрабатывающий данные
   базового класса - зависит от реализации иерархии классов
3. Каждый потомок переопределяет методы getData() и setData() с добавлением в
   возвращаемую строку своих данных и с обработкой принятых данных в соответствии со своей реализацией
4. В процессе записи данных в файл записываем последовательно сначала
   тип данных (объект какого класса сохраняем), если нужно, то длину
   сохраняемых данных, ну и сами данные, которые возвращает метод
   getData() сохраняемого объекта
5. В процессе чтения данных из файла анализируем тип сохраненного
   объекта, в соответствии с этим создаем новый экземпляр требуемого
   класса. Для созданного экземпляра вызываем метод setData() и
   передаем в него считанную из файла строку